# How can I output to the user additional information associated with the greatest value in an array?

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to get my code to output to the user the most popular sauce sold (numbers sold is based on user input), the sauce's name and its price. I can get it to display the greatest value but I cannot figure out how to also output the name and price in the same writeline. Here's what I have so far:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string[] names;
        names = new string[5];

        names [0] = "Eastern Carolina";
        names [1] = "Western Carolina";
        names [2] = "Kansas City";
        names [3] = "SC Mustard";
        names [4] = "Texas";

        int[] quantity;
        quantity = new int[5];

        double[] prices;
        prices = new double[5];

        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write ("Enter how many bottles of " + names[i] + " sold: ");
            quantity [i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine ());

            Console.Write ("Enter the price of " + names[i] + ": ");
            prices [i] = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());

        }

        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (names[i] +  " sauce $" + prices[i] + ", bottles sold: " + quantity [i]);
        }

        List<string> myList = new List<string> ();
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
            myList.Add (names[i] + " " + prices[i] + " " + quantity[i]);

        foreach (string name in myList)
            Console.WriteLine (name);


        if (quantity.Length > 0)
        {
            int large = quantity[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity.Length; i++)
            {
                if (large < quantity[i])
                {
                    large = quantity[i];
                    quantity[i] = large;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The most bottles sold is {0}", large);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the common attribute between you arrays is the index you should "save" that in your search.
So instead of

```
int large = quantity[0];
```

write

```
int large = 0;
```

and search by the index like this

```
if (quantity[large] < quantity[i])
{
    large = i;
}
```

I have no idea why you would set the quantity to large again, you don't need to do that. Afterwards you can access all the other arrays with `array[large]`.
You should consider using a class "Sauce" with attributes name, price and quatity instead of three arrays to keep your code structured.